# Is the Albers Equal Area projection only useful for calculating the area over small differences in longitude?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, pyproj

I've been trying to calculate the area of a map, given its WGS 84 coordinates, with the following code:

```py
import pyproj    
import shapely
import shapely.ops as ops
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from functools import partial


geom = Polygon([(-90, 40), (90, 40), (90, 45), (-90, 45), (-90, 40)])
geom_area = ops.transform(
    partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
        pyproj.Proj(
            proj='aea', 
            lat_0=(geom.bounds[1] + geom.bounds[3])/2
            lat_1=geom.bounds[1],
            lat_2=geom.bounds[3])),
    geom)

# Print the area in m^2
print(geom_area.area)
```

This works for the most part, but if I try it with the coordinates given in the code above, I get an area of `3303671782400.2344` square metres, while inputting the coordinates in GeoJSON gives me `8220117041870.774` square metres. I suspect that it may be that Albers Equal Area just isn't very accurate over such big differences in longitude, but I'd just like to confirm or know whether it's something else that I'm missing.

I've also tried it with other coordinates, for example I set `geom = Polygon([(-90, 40), (-100, 40), (-100, 45), (-90, 45), (-90, 40)])`, and the answer is fairly accurate at `455342769143.7002` versus `456673168992.82043` from GeoJSON.

Comment: Since it's a conic projection, exceeding a hemisphere is likely to cause trouble. +/-90 degrees is ~90 too far.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you have a recommendation on which projection to use that would give an accurate area for both big and small differences in longitude?

Comment: No, that would not be the approach I would use. Unfortunately this drifts too deeply into a broad opinion-based discussion for our focused Q/A model.

Comment: When using a projection to perform calculations, there is always some form of distortion involved, especially in the case of very large polygons like these. Densifying your segments can help reduce the error. The densification must be made while keeping in mind the actual geographic area that you wish to represent. For example, a geodetic densification here would cause the polygon to collapse into (more or less) a line passing through the North Pole. A densification made in a Plate Carree projection (Equirectangular projection) would result in a strip correponding to the latitude band 40°-45°